# Iterating through a tuple of tuples

Tags: python

I have a tuple of tuples and I want to get the second item of its tuple and I am pretty stack on it.Example of what I want:

```
t=((1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),)
```

and I want to get:

```
list=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Comment: Do you want to get a list, or a tuple in return, or does it not matter?

Comment: it really doesnt matter,I just want to know how to iterate through the tuples to get the second items pretty much,I just posted that so it can be an example of pretty much the goal.Sorry for not clarifying it

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension:

```
my_list = [entry[1] for entry in t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a list comprehension:

```
print([x for _, x in t])
```

Another (not really recommended solution):

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x[1], t)))
```

Both Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: If you write it this way I'd rather do
`[x for _, x in t]` to make it more clear that the other variable is being thrown away

Comment: @JohnO Good catch man, edited mine